# Run a python script as a windows service

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to run my python 3 script at system boot on windows 7?

I know this has been asked a couple of times, but none of the solutions really filled my needs, because I prefer to stay with the free python interpreter rather than switching to ActivePython.

I have installed the [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and would use py2exe, but it does not support Python 3.

Comment: I'd consider just using ActivePython if they went through the work for you. Otherwise, you can use a service wrapper like maybe: https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/ (I can't vouch for it, I've only used a different one for Java programs before. However it's free and claims to support any executable.)

Comment: Use SrvAny, it's really simple. See [Microsoft's  Description](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/de) and [about Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/146141/best-srvany-exe-for-windows-xp-and-windows-7).

Comment: I did it with winsw, which works great, is really easy to use and does not require any adjustments in my python code.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the Windows Task Scheduler using the following steps (skip quotes when typing):

- Search 'Task Scheduler' in Start button search box
- Create a new task
- In 'Create Task' dialog, go to 'Triggers' tab and click 'New' button
- Select 'At startup' from the 'Begin the task' dropdown, click 'OK'
- Go to 'Actions' tab and click 'New' button
- 'Action' dropdown should show 'Start a program'
- In 'Program/script' box, type 'python.exe'
- In 'Add arguments' box, type the full path to your python script with any arguments, such as 'C:\Scripts\startupscript.py -c onstart'

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a fully woking stand alone exe file that's been generated from your python script using `py2exe`, you can just add a new string with some random key and value as the `absolute path` of your exe file under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` of `windows registry` (accessible by running `regedit` from Window's `run` prompt). This will run the exe file whenever your Windows 7 boots up !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sc` command. I am unable to test it right now but i think it would look like this:

```
sc create MyCoolService start=auto binpath=c:\mycoolprogram\supercool.exe obj=LocalSystem displayname=CoolService
```

[See link for command syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289.aspx)