# How to create a windows service of python script, when the script has lot of dependency files?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I have referred [Chris Umbel's blog](https://www.chrisumbel.com/article/windows_services_in_python) to create a python windows service. I am not sure how this will work if i a have a dependecy python_read_email.py file for this service. How to create such services where I have bunch of files which are dependent.

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event
import python_read_email


class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    # you can NET START/STOP the service by the following name
    _svc_name_ = "PySvc"
    # this text shows up as the service name in the Service
    # Control Manager (SCM)
    _svc_display_name_ = "Python Test Service"
    # this text shows up as the description in the SCM
    _svc_description_ = "This service writes stuff to a file"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        # create an event to listen for stop requests on
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    # core logic of the service   
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager

        rc = None

        # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            python_read_email.run()
            # block for 5 seconds and listen for a stop event
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)

    # called when we're being shut down    
   `def SvcStop(self):
        # tell the SCM we're shutting down
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        # fire the stop event
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)
```

Comment: I prefer to run it as 'scheduled task' (especially when your code isn't thread safe and/or requires to run in an single thread), this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022002/run-a-python-script-as-a-windows-service

Comment: You wrote: "I am not sure how this will work...". Did you try it? Was there a problem?

Comment: Yes I tried to create a service but it is not running as intended.