# Program using screenshots on Windows 10 server errors upon SSH disconnection

Tags: python, windows, ssh, server, image-recognition

I have a Python program running on a Windows 10 server hosted online, which locates specific icons using screenshots. The program uses image recognition to identify these icons. However, when I disconnect from SSH, the program errors out due to the absence of an active screen.

How can I allow it to function even when not directly connected via SSH, ensuring it can continue locating and interacting with these icons/ the screen?

Comment: So you ssh into the server to run the program? Or is it always running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125493/how-to-constantly-run-python-script-in-the-background-on-windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022002/run-a-python-script-as-a-windows-service https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh

Comment: Ignore the last one, that's for linux, you should just run the script as a service, then you could even add conditions to restart it if it closes itself or errors.

Comment: making it a service is not possible since services are not allowed to interact with gui for security on windows

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/735442/stay-logged-in-while-rdp-session-is-over

the marked answer worked for me

tscon 1 /dest:console ; Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe" -ArgumentList '"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\script\script.py"'